# STM32F303C8 code not entering the while Loop

Tags: stm32, cortex-m, cubemx

I have tried everything and am at real loss here.

The Problem Statement:
The code does not enter the while loop.

1.Working on STM32F303C8.

2.I have three boards:

```
Nucleo F303RE
Nucleo F303K8
Custom board.
```

All have the same IC and are giving the same problem. So the problem must be software related.

3. I have posted the entire code and the cubeMX file on BitBucket. Please find the link here:[Link for CubeMx Software](https://bitbucket.org/indiaaditya/stm32cube_stackxchange/src/master/)
   [TrueStudio Project](https://bitbucket.org/indiaaditya/truestudiorepoforc_code/src/master/)

Edit 1: Relevant Code here

```
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f3xx_hal.h"
#include "i2c.h"
#include "iwdg.h"
#include "spi.h"
#include "tim.h"
#include "usart.h"
#include "gpio.h"
#include "arm_math.h"


/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
unsigned int uiCntr;
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_NVIC_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  *
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_SMBUS_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_TIM6_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_IWDG_Init();

  /* Initialize interrupts */
  //MX_NVIC_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  while(1){
      uiCntr++;
  }
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit;

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSIState = RCC_LSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_I2C1;
  PeriphClkInit.I2c1ClockSelection = RCC_I2C1CLKSOURCE_HSI;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/**
  * @brief NVIC Configuration.
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_NVIC_Init(void)
{
  /* TIM6_DAC1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM6_DAC1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM6_DAC1_IRQn);
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  file: The file name as string.
  * @param  line: The line in file as a number.
  * @retval None
  */
void _Error_Handler(char *file, int line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */`
```

4. The code simply refuses to enter the while loop.
5. If the IWDG init function is removed the code remains stuck at the last init function call in the sequence. If IWDG is commented, it jumps back to start of the code and executes till beginning of the while loop.
6. Could it be the startup file?

Thanks in advance for the support.

Kind Regards,
Aditya Ayachit

Comment: Please post the relevant code rather than a link.

Comment: You confirmed the peripherals you are talking to have had their clocks enabled? If you try to access a peripheral in reset or with gated clocks it may not respond and may hang the processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.
Pretty silly but may be helpful to people starting out using HAL.
As responded by old_timer, the issue was indeed related to Time base.

The root cause:
The Timer 6 was being initialized but it's timer base needs to be initialized separately.
The solution:
After calling the function `MX_TIM6_Init`, integrated the function `HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim6)`.
This solved the problem. Also note that since I am using TImer 6 in interrupt mode, I need HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT function. Otherwise you should call the `HAL_TIM_Base_Start` function.

Kind Regards,

Aditya Ayachit